# Where can I learn more about cita niyama?

Tags: laws

In [What is the Buddhist point of view of the Law of Attraction?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-is-the-buddhist-point-of-view-of-the-law-of-attraction/2487?noredirect=1#comment3190_2487)

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/295/suminda-sirinath-salpitikorala says that law of attraction is part of citta niyama.

Where can I learn more about it? How come thinking about something affect the outcome that I am thinking about? I know of many ways actually. However, are there complete listings on how this come to be?

Answer (score 2):

Following is a link to the Niyama Dhammas in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niyama). Following is a translation from [Pali Sources](http://www.jayarava.org/texts/the-five-Fold-niyama.pdf). Also this is a text by [Ledi Sayadaw called "THE NIYAMA-DIPANI: The Manual of Cosmic Order"](http://mahajana.net/texts/kopia_lokalna/MANUAL04.html).

If you have the power of deep [Jhana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhy%C4%81na_in_Buddhism) and make a strong [determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhi%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81na) (which is part of the [perfections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81ramit%C4%81)) then there is a possibility that the something similar desired outcome materialises based on the power of your mind (depending how deep the absorption [Samadhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samadhi_(Buddhism)) is). This can be done to a more limited extent without Samadhi also as this moment influences the next as per [Dependent Origination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da).

But this is not recommended as this may generate bad [Kamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma_in_Buddhism) as this practice can lead to covetousness. See [Kammapatha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kammapatha). Also such use of Samadhi will not be [Samma Samashi](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-samadhi/).

Matter of clarification, these are two concepts but there are much similarities.

I hope this helps. Comment if you want more information.